# PHP file upload suddenly stopped working

Tags: php, file-upload

I had file upload working fine this morning and did a couple of test uploads using small csv files, but when I did another test it has stopped working.

var_dump of $_FILES['file'] is NULL, and trying if($_FILES) produces nothing.
No one else uses my server so I know nothing's been changed.
Here is my form which posts to the same page.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="border:1px solid #999">
                <input type="file">
                <input type="hidden" name="customerID" value="<?=$_GET['customerID']?>">
                <input type="submit" value="Import">
            </form>
```

Php handler:

```
if($_FILES)
{
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        $path = "files/".$_POST['customerID']."/";

        echo $path."<br>";

        if(!file_exists($path)) mkdir($path);

        $path = $path.basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

        echo $path."<br>".$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']."<br>";

        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))
        {
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path)) echo "Upload success";

            else echo "Upload failed";
        }
        else echo "No temp file";
    }
```

Comment: You need to show us your PHP handler also. However, you may need to `name` your `<input type="file">` which seems to be the most likely cause, without seeing full code.

Comment: Are you on a shared-hosting platform? GoDaddy, HostGator? `echo ini_get('upload_max_filesize').'<br>'.ini_get('post_max_size');`. Also check the network tab of your Console (F12) to see if something is failing there.

Comment: php handler on there now, it's the same as before which worked, I also didn't have the name attribute either

Comment: print_r($_POST), print_r($_FILES)

Comment: I'm not on a shared host; my upload_max_filesize & post_max_size are both 1G, files I'm uploaded are 165KB max

Comment: print_r($_POST), print_r($_FILES) produces Array ( [customerID] => 149 ) Array ( )

Comment: Your handler is looking for a file named `file` - `$_FILES['file']['name']` - but you haven't named your input `<input type="file">` --- try `<input type="file" name="file">` @user2622416

Comment: @user2622416 Had you bothered looking here ^^^^^ over 7 minutes ago, you'd of been up and running 6 minutes earlier ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had to change something... because $_FILES['file'] should be undefined in code you gave. No file is sent at all by most browsers in the case when file input has no name attribute in HTML form.

Simply change:

`<input type="file">`

to

`<input type="file" name="file">`

Comment: You're right that's it, I thought it didn't have it before but it must have done, thanks all.

Comment: 15:21:54 < my timestamp --- 15:22:29 yours. ;-)

Comment: Sorry then, not my fault. I was writting it when you commented. Didn't see your comment yet. I'm not one of those who care about points in here. Just wanted to help.

Comment: It's ok Flash. The OP didn't bother reading my comment from over 5-6 minutes ago. Proves that comments aren't worth the paper they're written on ;-) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a "name" attribute to your `<input type="file">`. The name you give to the input will be the index of the array element in $_FILES that contains the uploaded file data.